# How do I make Selenium Driver in Python wait until .get() page loads fully to get entire page source?

Tags: python, selenium

My Selenium Driver is suddenly receiving None when requesting from a page. I want to store url`x` inside dictionary `data` but my `driver.get(x)` is returning None.

```
self.data= {
"google.com": page_source,
"stackoverflow.com/....": page_source,
etc...
}
```

I tried using

```
self.data[link] = self.driver.get(link)
            
  try:
       self.data[link] = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.NAME, "?"))
  finally:
       continue
```

but it doesnt seem to stop and wait, also I don't want to wait for a specific element, I want for the entire page to finish loading.

I've also tried to use `driver.implicity_wait(10)` but it doesnt seem to wait at all.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Reference this answer to the above question.

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
pageSource = driver.page_source
fileToWrite = open("page_source.html", "w")
fileToWrite.write(pageSource)
fileToWrite.close()
fileToRead = open("page_source.html", "r")
print(fileToRead.read())
fileToRead.close()
driver.quit()
```